# Using conditions again and again or just create different methods

Tags: c#, conditions

I have a method,

```
function DoThis(bool isHuman)
{
  // Do something

  if(isHuman)
  {
    //call his dad
  }
  else
  {
    //its a animal - let animal resuce know
  }


  // add some blah blah code
  // some more blah blah code

  if(isHuman)
  {
    //call his mother
  }
  else
  {
    heheeee now heeeheee
  }

  // more code



}
```

Should I keep Using conditions again and again or just create different methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious refactoring is to remove the duplication like this:

```
  if(isHuman)
  {
    //call his dad
    doCommonStuff()
    //call his mother
  }
  else
  {
    // do animal stuff
    doCommonStuff()
    // do more animal stuff
  }
```

Don't be afraid to introduce well-named methods, even if they are only called once. It's the single best way of increasing readability.

Answer (score 1):

Well if it makes sense you can probably use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or some other trick with [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Note, these methods require you send an object since they rely on function overloading. You can maybe use the `isHuman` to create dummy object just for the sake of the dispatching, but I guess that if you look at your code at a larger scale, you probably find an object that you want to send instead of the `isHuman` and can be used for the design pattern.

If you are not familiar with function overloading you maybe want to start learning about [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Answer (score 0):

The Template Method Pattern applies to such situations.

```
void DoThis() {
  FirstSpecificPart();
  common code
  SecondSpecificPart();
}

void Human.FirstSpecificPart() {
  call(dad)
}
void Animal.FirstSpecificPart() {
  call(animal shelter)
}
```